# How to pass user defined variables file in Jmeter through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I need to execute the same jmx file for two different environments. The user-defined variable for both is different. How to pass user-defined variables through Jenkins to overcome that.

Answer (score 0):

In Jemeter you should be able to read properties either from Environment variables, System variables or property files. You can refer [this](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#envsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) for reading from environment variables.

Then in Jenkins you can set the environment variables before executing your Jmeter script. There are many ways to do this in Jenkins. Following is a multi-stage example.

```
stage('Dev Testing') {
            steps {
                script {
                         sh '''
                           TEST_HOST="http://dev.com"
                           {JMETER EXEcution}
                         '''
                   }

            }
        }
        
        stage('QA Testing') {
            steps {
                script {
                        sh '''
                           TEST_HOST="http://qa.com"
                           {JMETER EXEcution}
                        '''
                   }
            }
        }
```

**Other Options**

Also as I mentioned you can use [System properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or property files with Jemter scripts. [This](https://octoperf.com/blog/2019/01/14/flexible-test-plans/#simple-external-properties-file) is a good tutorial for this. Once you set this up in the Jmeter script you can either generate the property file from Jenkins or use an appropriate property file based on the environment. Or you can pass the properties directly to the Jemeter script as shown below.

```
jmeter -Jgroup1.threads=7 -Jhostname1=www.realhost.edu
```

Comment: Thank you so much ycr. As your answer, two different environments can be identified. Is there a way two differentiate user defined variables. For the dev and staging, we have different user defined parameter values. I need to manage two different user defined variables values also in same jmx file.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you saying that depending on the environment you will have a different set of parameters as well?

Comment: Yes, Depending on the environment, i have different user parameters. As an example: username and password are parameters. But Those are different as the environment. I have to maintain two user-defined variables for two environments. But need to use same script.

Comment: Isn't username and password variables common to all environments? The values assigned would change but I suppose variables are going to be the same.

Comment: not same.. values are also different environment to environment